# Can't link to lib after VS2010 upgrade (__cdecl vs __thiscall?)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, cdecl

Any help much appreciated, my forehead's getting bruised.

We have a big open source `DICOM` library (`dcmtk`) we use as a static lib. It's unmanaged C++, and we're linking to it from a managed `C++ DLL` that wraps it. It uses CMake to munge up the build instructions for various platforms. Moving to `VS2010` (from 2008) broke our build, so we took the opportunity to update the library version we’re using as well (which should be more `VS2010` friendly). After some screwing around the lib now builds (give or take a zillion warnings about type conversions). But now the code that uses it won’t link to it. It throws a bunch of unresolved external symbol errors.

It’s finding the library OK (if I change the lib filename it craps out earlier on w/ an appropriate msg).

If I disassemble the lib file with DUMPBIN I see the appropriate tokens, e.g.:
…
  000000000000000E: C3                 ret

`??1OFString@@QEAA@XZ (public: __cdecl OFString::~OFString(void))`:

```
0000000000000000: 40 53              push        rbx…
```

but the linker doesn’t find it:

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall OFString::~OFString(void)" (??1OFString@@QAE@XZ)
```

I’ve been working the theory that it’s the `__cdecl vs. __thiscall` mismatch, but haven’t been able to get VS to build the lib with any other convention. (Ironically the old 2008 version, which does `emit __thiscall`, seems to be compiled with /Gd option that I thought `forces __cdecl`).

Any insights?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can see the name mangling is different.  Using undname.exe might help your cause:

```
Undecoration of :- "??1OFString@@QEAA@XZ"
is :- "public: __cdecl OFString::~OFString(void) __ptr64"
```

versus:

```
Undecoration of :- "??1OFString@@QAE@XZ"
is :- "public: __thiscall OFString::~OFString(void)"
```

Also, are you doing a mix of x64 and x86?

Comment: Looked right at it, and didn't see the mangle difference -- thanks. The lib is building for x64. The managed DLL was building Win32, now set to x64 it's down to a couple of dozen unresolved symbols. The one above was resolved...will find details on the remaining...